# Extract image sources in C# from web page using JS

Tags: c#

UPDATE #2 Continuing on this effort (see original and update #1 below).  ScrapySharp had potential but no matter what I tried, the process consumed all available memory and didn't produce anything.  I did find that, due to jQuery, in a test WebBrowser control, the correct web page does not load.  It seems the site has a function that determines how you got to the page requested, validates something about your browser, and redirects you to a generic sign-up page.

**Thoughts on how to appease the gate keeper?**

UPDATE #1 (details of original, not unique question below):
First of all - THANK YOU!  For the suggestions!

I tried to use ScrapySharp as @John pointed out as:

```
    ScrapingBrowser Browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
    WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("http://www.example-site.com"));
    HtmlNode rawHTML = PageResult.Html;
    Console.WriteLine(rawHTML.InnerHtml);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

However, it resulted in a memory leak.  To get a sense of how it works, I tried:

```
            ScrapingBrowser Browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
            WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri(url));
            HtmlNode rawHTML = PageResult.Html;
            var imgNodes = rawHTML.SelectNodes("//img");
```

Which also created a memory leak.  What am I missing with my implementation of it?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I'm trying to get my application to grab specific images from a web site.  So far I've been using HtmlAgilityPack but it only grabs the basic HTML.  I don't know how to explain the tags from the missing elements other than they show up when using Inspect in Chrome (but Regex and HtmlAgilityPack can't seem to access/see them), and they have a "data-v-??????" identifier inside the tag.  Here's an example:

```
<div data-v-1a7a6550="" class="product-extra-images"><img data-v-1a7a6550="" src="https://vw-xerophane.storage.googleapis.com:443/thumbnails/products/34160_1Earring5th-5-18_1.jpg.100x100_q85_crop_upscale.jpg" width="50"><img data-v-1a7a6550="" src="https://vw-xerophane.storage.googleapis.com:443/thumbnails/products/34160_2Earring5th-5-18_1.jpg.100x100_q85_crop_upscale.jpg" width="50"></div>
```

Please let me know if you need additional details.  Here's a sample of my latest code that couldn't extract the elements (in case it helps):

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
                {
                    OptionFixNestedTags = true,
                    OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
                    OptionReadEncoding = false
                };

                var imgNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");

                foreach (var imgNode in imgNodes)
                {
                    //decode the string
                    var img = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(imgNode.InnerText).Trim();

                    imagesouces.Add(img);
                }

                File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\WriteText.txt", imagesouces);
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion by @HereticMonkey first since that was the easiest to implement.  It still couldn't grab the data.  I'll try the one provided by John next.  Thank you both!

Comment: Updated question with additional details and develpments noted and resolved here (in case anyone later needs to resolve a similar issue):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971088/c-sharp-scrape-correct-web-content-following-jquery/52972739?noredirect=1#comment92852730_52972739